# Invalid Hook call in a functional element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this annoying error, but don't know why.

I have 2 functional elements, just starting for test purposes.

Main:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MapaLogisplan from './Layout/MapaLogisplan'
//import DlgInfo from './Layout/DlgInfo'
//import MenuGeneral from './layout/MenuGeneral'
import ReadDlgInfoData from './data/DlgInfoData.js'


const LogisplanMain = () => {
    const [TrucksData, setTrucksData] = useState([]);
    const [TrucksColumnas, setTrucksColumnas] = useState([]);

    //se llama cuando se renderiza. (el return la llama).
    useEffect(() => {
        const [ datos, columnas ] = ReadDlgInfoData({ Nombredatos: 'Trucks', Matricula: '' });
        setTrucksData(datos);
        setTrucksColumnas(columnas);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <MapaLogisplan />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<LogisplanMain />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import soapRequest from 'easy-soap-request';
import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';


//PROPS:{Nombredatos(WS),TruckPlate===""->Todos.}
const ReadDlgInfoData = (props) => {
    const [datos, setDatos] = useState([]);
    const [columnas, setColumnas] = useState([]);
    const url = `http://DAVID-PC:800`;
    const sampleHeaders = {
        'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'soapAction': 'Da igual',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, *'
    };
.....
```

I can't find why it complains about:

```
**Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:14906)
    at useState (react.development.js:1508)
    at ReadDlgInfoData (DlgInfoData.js:23)
    at app.tsx:15
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
throwInvalidHookError @ react-dom.development.js:14906
useState @ react.development.js:1508
ReadDlgInfoData @ DlgInfoData.js:23
(anónimo) @ app.tsx:15
```

Any tip of light on how to get it corrected would be appreciated, as I'm starting to work with React I'm lost.

I've checked the 3 possible causes but didn't find anything.

1. React and React-Dom are 17.0 versions.
2. I call useState and useEffect at the top of their respective functional elements.
3. I think I'm not using React in more than one place. If I delete the second import in the
   ReadDlgInfoData functional component nothing changes.

So I'm stuck at this point and I have tried all the things I know I can try.
Invalid Hook:
[image: Invalid Hook]

Comment: `ReadDlgInfoData` looks like it is a react component and you are calling it from the `useEffect` of `LogisplanMain`. Is `ReadDlgInfoData` supposed to be a custom hook?

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const [ datos, columnas ] = ReadDlgInfoData({ Nombredatos: 'Trucks', Matricula: '' });
    setTrucksData(datos);
    setTrucksColumnas(columnas);
 }, []);
```

Here is the problem, you destructure your values inside of useEffect, which is  against hook rules.

```
 const [ datos, columnas ] = ReadDlgInfoData({ Nombredatos: 'Trucks', Matricula: '' });
 useEffect(() => {
    setTrucksData(datos);
    setTrucksColumnas(columnas);
 }, []);
```

This should solve your problem.